# Finding a parent node to a child node in a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I was trying to make a function that gets a child node and a binary tree and returns the parent node of that given child. If the child node given is the root it should return null. 
This is what I was trying to do :

```
//input : The function gets a binary tree and a child node
//output : The function returns the parent of a given child of the tree, if the given child is the root
//then it will return null
public static BinTreeNode<Character> Parent(BinTreeNode<Character> bt, BinTreeNode<Character> child){
    if(bt==null){
        return bt;
    }
    else{
        if(bt.hasLeft()&&(bt.hasRight())){
            if((bt.getLeft().getValue()==child.getValue())||(bt.getRight().getValue()==child.getValue())){
                return bt;
            }
            else{
                Parent(bt.getLeft(),child);
                Parent(bt.getRight(),child);

            }
        }
        if(bt.hasLeft()){
            if(bt.getLeft().getValue()==child.getValue()){
                return bt;
            }
            else{
                return Parent(bt.getLeft(),child);
            }
        }
        if(bt.hasRight()){
            if(bt.getRight().getValue()==child.getValue()){
                return bt;
            }
            else{
                return Parent(bt.getRight(),child);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

for some reason it keeps returning me null, after debugging I saw that when it gets to the first condition it checks if it equals but then instead of continuing in the recursion towards the other conditions and what I told it to do it just went staring to the return null at the bottom and I don't know why?
I will be very thankful for any help I an kind of new to java.

Comment: You need to return the values from the recursive calls if they are non-null: `return Parent(bt.getLeft(),child);` etc

Comment: My Parent function gets a tree of characters- a is root, e left child-has 2 children c left and b right, g right child ((((null c null) e (null b null)) a ((null d null) g null))
and also the child node where I created a new Node BinTreeNode<Character> child=new BinTreeNode<Character>('e');
BinTreeNode<Character> ParentNode=Parent(t,child);

Comment: Well I had the return and then deleted it, I also decided to delete the condition where both children aren't null because I just want to go through all left and all right children until I reach the child I to find it's parent, However, it still returns null

Answer (score 2):

You need to walk through the tree before return it.

Your implementation is only walking left and then returning null (probably your child is on the right)...

Try something like that:

```
public static BinTreeNode<Character> getParent(BinTreeNode<Character> 
bt, BinTreeNode<Character> child){
    if(bt==null){
        return bt;
    }
    BinTreeNode<Character> left = null;
    BinTreeNode<Character> right = null;
    if(bt.hasLeft()){
        if(bt.getLeft().equals(child))
            return bt;
        left = getParent(bt.getLeft(),child);
    }
    if(left == null){
        if(bt.hasRight()) {
            if(bt.getRight().equals(child))
                return bt;
            right = getParent(bt.getRight(),child);
        }
    } else {
        return left;
    }
    return right;
}
```

Here we have an implementation of Depth-first search.

Comment: Thanks it works! Can you explain a bit about what you actually did? I desperately tried to go through the entire tree-thus the many conditions but I only managed to check one side whereas in other recursive methods I did in the past I was able to go through the entire tree writing something rather similar like return(t.getLeft())&&(t.getRight()) but it didn't let me this time. So can you explain a bit what you did in words?I kind of understand but not completely. Anyway I'm very thankful for your help.

Comment: in fact, the only big difference is that instead of returning directly from the recursion call, we stores the results in variables. With this you always try to go left first and only go right when left returns null. What you did was almost right, but you returns directly on the left check (never checking the children from the right side).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you will only ever check all the left children. So your code will only work for children on the left (of children on the left, etc). Once you reach the bottom, you return `null` and that's it.

To fix it, change your code to the following:

```
public static BinTreeNode<Character> parent(BinTreeNode<Character> bt, BinTreeNode<Character> child) {
    if (bt == null) {
        return bt;
    } else {
        if (bt.hasLeft()) {
            if (bt.getLeft().equals(child)) {
                return bt;
            }

            BinTreeNode<Character> possibleParent = parent(bt.getLeft(), child);
            if (possibleParent != null) {
                return possibleParent;
            }
        }

        if (bt.hasRight()) {
            if (bt.getRight().equals(child)) {
                return bt;
            } else {
                return parent(bt.getRight(), child);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And it'll work.

Comment: If the node has no left child, you never check right one.